# I'm confused about python virtualenv is the interpreter located within it or on my mac

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I'm confused about how my virtualenv works and If i have some clarity on this I think it will help me understand what my dillema is. Is the interpreter located within my virtualenv? or is it on my mac? what confuses me is how I can have different versions of python in the vertualenv but then says I have to choose my interpreter which seems to be outside the environment. i thought when I ran

```
virtualenv -p python3 <my_serv>
```

that my interpreter was included inside of my virtualenv. But from the documentation I've gleaned it seems that may not be the case. and if it's not the interpreter is it the executable of python3 that I am adding?

Comment: What says you "have to choose [your] interpreter"?  Are you referring to the use of the `-p` option when creating the virtualenv or to something later?

Comment: @Jwodder in the hitchhikers guide to python the author "You can also use the Python interpreter of your choice (like python2.7)."  $ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_project thats the location of my python on my mac. Which is odd to me because If i'm creating an environment to keep everything separate and supposedly comes with it's own interpreter why choose the one that's on your system? why not just use the one you created

Comment: `virtualenv` doesn't create a brand-new Python out of nothing; it has to either copy or symlink a pre-existing `python` executable and standard library, and it gets those from your system.  After the virtual environment has been created, packages you add & remove in it won't affect your system's Python, and *vice versa* (unless site packages are enabled).

Comment: The virtualenv will only have one version of Python associated with it. That is why you will want to provide the version in this way. To answer your question on location. This does not create a virtualized machine of any kind its just created a self contained folder which has Python in it. When you call Python from within that virtualenv you are using that Python binary.

Comment: @jwodder you rally cleared it up for me